# Padding, margins, and background color leaving mobile version unoptimized?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm looking to add black padding/margins to my long-form sales page.
[example of black margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEgF1.png).
Looks great when I enter the following code into the head when viewing on desktop.
However, when I take a look on any mobile, its just awful - margins from the code are applied to the mobile version so it looks scrunched up into a barely-legible web page.

How can I make these margins appear on desktop view and not affect the mobile appearance?

Not so keen with any of this, and tried the lazy-man's approach by inserting this into just the html head...will this take some CSS coding?

Thanks.

```html
<style>
  html { 
      background-color: black;
  }
  body { 
      margin:75px; 
      margin-top:0px; 
      background-color: white; 
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what are known as **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. These allow you to write CSS rules which only target specific viewports, and are denoted by `@media`.

If you want your code to only apply for desktops, you can use somethjing like the following:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    background-color: black;
  }
  body {
    margin: 75px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

The above will only apply your rules to viewports that are `768px` wide or wider (which covers tablets, laptops and desktops). If you want a more finely-tuned media query, you can check out CSSTricks' article on **[media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)**. A fairly comprehensive list of device viewport sizes can be found **[here](http://viewportsizes.mattstow.com/)**.

Note that you can make use of multiple media queries for multiple different viewports, and if you're using a responsive framework like Bootstrap, Skeleton or Toast, then several media queries will be baked in by default.